# Quality of webcam not as good as when running under Windows

Tags: dell, webcam

I have a Dell Inspiron 1520 laptop with a Creative 2.0 MP webcam built-in, running on Ubuntu 10.10. Earlier I was using Windows Vista which came pre-installed with my laptop. The quality of camera was very good, but now on Ubuntu the quality of the webcam is really really bad; any idea why that is so, and how to fix the problem?

Comment: The information provided is not sufficient in this question. "low quality" is a vary vague subjective term. Be more specific by using terms like noise, brightness, contrast, colour vibrance, flickering, etc. And the minimum would be to provide a screenshot/picture to compare.